# Tailwind 3 update styles on save not working if Tailwind directives imported in angular component

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have a component in app folder and in that component styles file i added the Tailwind directives

**src/app/my-component/my-component.scss**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

when i run ng build all tailwind classes builded correctly, but then i add new classes to my templates tailwind will not rebuild with new classes.

if i import Tailwind directives into **/src/styles.css** all works as expected. But default solution not suited for my app because this angular app is used in module federation app and main app don't use tailwind

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to handle these cases is by using the CLI and either adding a concurrent build in your npm start or running it separated. this way you can add any config in the module or component level.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#it-just-isn-t-working-properly